# Не добавляются элементы зарегистрированными пользователями

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте.
В чем может быть причина того, что пользователи не могут создать новый элемент?
На странице сайте есть форма комментариев:

```
<?if($USER->GetID()):?>
    <form name="comment" action="<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurUri(); ?>" method="POST">
       Ваш комментарий:<br/>
       <textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="comtext"></textarea><br/>
      <input type="s ubmit" value="Отправить" name="iblock_submit">
   </form><br/><br/>
<?endif;?>
```

Добавление комментариев:

```
if($_POST["comtext"]):
$PROP2 = array();
$PROP2[63] = $arResult["ID"];
$arCommentArray2 = Array(  
"PROPERTY_VALUES"=> $PROP2,
"MODIFIED_BY"    => $USER->GetID(),
"IBLOCK_ID"      => 12,
"IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => false, 
"NAME"           => $arResult["ID"],  
"ACTIVE"         => "Y",  
"DETAIL_TEXT"    => $_POST["comtext"]   
);
$PRODUCT_ID = $el2->Add($arCommentArray2);
endif;
```

Когда комментарии добавляются под админом то все нормально. Остальные зарегистрированные пользователи не могут добавить комментарий, элемент просто не создается.

При чем есть еще одна особенность, стоит мне поменять тип доступа к инфоблоку в админке, и юзеры могут добавить комментарий 1 раз, после добавления опять тупик.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

У вас не стоят права на запись в инфоблок, это делается в настройках инфоблока, последння вкладка.